# How do I fix the webpack file for the React Router issue?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am having the cannot get /path from react router. This is my webpack file. What do I need to change to make it work even for url/path1/path2

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Are you using webpack dev server to serve the files? Is this happening in development?

Comment: in development and yes I am using webpack dev server

Comment: Can you try adding public path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem I fixed it by defining an entry point, the output, made historyAPIFullback as true

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
      
        // add outputs
        
        output: {
          publicPath: '/',
        },
      
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

hope this helps.

Comment: nothing, and I think output should be outside the module

Comment: did you try it when it is outside ?

Comment: sure but nothing happens